# Finding the variance of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, definite-integrals, python

In an attempt to find the variance of a function continuous in the interval $S = [a,b]$.

I have proposed a solution. But am afraid that I have something wrong over here. And before any further explanation I need to clarify that I am currently in high school year 11 so please consider my range of knowledge! without any further a do here is my attempt.

---

For any continuous function $f(x)$ we can define
$$
\tag{*}
M\{f\}(a, b) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, dx.
$$
From here we will use a theorem that states:
$$
\tag{**}
\sigma^2 = (\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}^N x_i^2) - x_{avg}^2.
$$
Here note that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}^N x_i^2$ is just the average of the set $S$ where $S = \{x_i|i\in[1, N]\land i\in N\}$ now if we need to find the average of some function $f$ from the theorem $(*)$  we can find it. So let's plug all of that in:
$$
\tag{***}
(*)(**) \implies \sigma^2\{f\}(a, b) = M\{x^2\}(a, b)-[M\{f\}(a, b)]^2 = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b}x^2 dx - [\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx]^2.
$$
Now when I input the function $\sigma^2\{\sin x\}(-3, 3)$ wolfram alpha outputs 3 but on the other hand I have written a code which divides an interval into pieces and computes the value of the function at each slicing point and then it computes the variance of the collected data which it claims to be about $0.523254$ here is the code:

```
def mean(data):
    return sum(data) / len(data)

def variance(data):
    mean_flt = mean(data)
    return sum([(i ** 2) / len(data) for i in data]) - mean_flt ** 2

def split_interval(interval, section):
    step = (interval[1] - interval[0]) / section
    array = []
    i = interval[0]
    while i <= interval[-1]:
        array.append(i)
        i += step

    return array[:]

function = lambda x : math.sin(x)
dataset = [function(i) for i in split_interval([-3, 3], 100)]
var = variance(dataset)

print("var-rep-100 : ", var)
```

please help me see my mistakes whether it is in the code or it is in the math!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is $\int_a^b x^2 dx$? That definitely doesn't seem right to me (I haven't gone through the rest of maths yet). Maybe you meant $\int_a^b f(x)^2 dx$?

Comment: @GarethMa, you are right, OP miswrote that part, but the calculation used the right version.

Comment: Have you used a larger "section" size than 100? Notice that since $\sin$ is odd, the square of the mean is just $0$. I suspect that you haven't used enough samples for that part to vanish enough, resulting in the smaller result.

Comment: @ManateePink I suspect that's not the problem - implementing his formula using the corrected version I suggested in Sage as `(integrate(f(x)^2, x, a, b) / (b - a) - (integrate(f(x), x, a, b) / (b - a))^2).n()`, i get 0.5232846248499, which matches his numerical results

Comment: @ManateePink yes i have tried for over 10^7 section sizes and the result doesn't differ much

Comment: @iliavarnasseri Can you show us how you got the $3$ from supposedly wolfram alpha?

Comment: @GarethMa here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B1%2C6%5DIntegrate%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D+-+Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C6%5DIntegrate%5Bsinx%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D

Comment: Yeah, as I stated your formula is wrong.

Comment: never mind I got it...rookie mistake! I should have used $M\{f^2(x)\}(a, b)$ instead of $M\{x^2\}(a, b)$...I am now mortified! thank you by the way!

Comment: @GarethMa, ah, yeah, forgot to divide by 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it should be $\int_a^b [f(x)]^2 dx$ instead of $\int_a^b x^2 dx$. So your formula for variance should be $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b \sin^2(x) dx - \frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b \sin(x) dx$. Notice that it's not $\sin(x^2)$ either since your random variable is $Y = \sin(X)$. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250391/variance-of-a-function-of-a-random-variable) for example.

Indeed, implementing this in sage matches your results for Python:

```
sage: x = var('x')
sage: f = sin(x)
sage: a = -3
sage: b = 3
sage: (integrate(f(x)^2, x, a, b) / (b - a) - (integrate(f(x), x, a, b) / (b - a))^2).n()
# 0.523284624849910
```

Exact result is $\frac{1}{6}\int_{-3}^3 \sin^2(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12}\sin(6)$.

Another Python implementation:

````
import numpy as np # for .var (variance)

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000000)
y = np.sin(x)
print(np.var(y))
# 0.5232841214798628
```
````